# Render span-level string using Kramdown

Tags: ruby, kramdown

I know that I can parse and render an HTML document with Kramdown in ruby using something like

```
require 'kramdown'

s = 'This is a _document_'
Kramdown::Document.new(s).to_html
# '<p>This is a <i>document</i></p>'
```

In this case, the string `s` may contain a full document in markdown syntax.

What I want to do, however, is to parse `s` assuming that it only contains span-level markdown syntax, and obtain the rendered html. In particular there should be no `<p>`, `<blockquote>`, or, e.g., `<table>` in the rendered html.

```
s = 'This is **only** a span-level string'
# .. ??? ...
# 'This is <b>only</b> a span-level string'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to strip out all block-level elements? This is the default behavior of kramdown. See http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html

Comment: That's also what I read, but the output still contains the `p`'s. Haven't figured out how to get kramdown to actually remove those.

Comment: It appears that option is for parsing raw HTML; it doesn't have an effect on the output. The output is not changeable, as they aim to be consistent with other Markdown implementations. You'll probably have to post-process.

Comment: you could just postprocess with nokogiri quite easily.

Comment: Sanitize uses Nokogiri under the hood, it's even easier.

Answer (score 2):

I would post-process the output with the `sanitize` gem.

```
require 'sanitize'

html = Kramdown::Document.new(s).to_html
output = Sanitize.fragment(html, elements:['b','i','em'])
```

The elements are a whitelist of allowed tags, just add all the tags you want. The gem has a set of predefined whitelists, but none match exactly what you're looking for. (BTW, if you want a list of all the HTML5 elements allowed in a span, see the [WHATWG's list of "phrasing content"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)).

I know this wasn't tagged [rails](/questions/tagged/rails), but for the benefit of readers using Rails: use the built-in [sanitize helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html).

Comment: I would rather *not add* the additional markup than have it removed. But if there is no other simple solution, I might just do this.

Comment: For security purposes, whitelists are preferred over blacklists. This is particularly a concern if the content is end-user created and the application generates public pages.

Comment: Sure, I always keep that in mind. But, in my case, the content is created by myself, not an end-user. Sanitation (somewhat) does what I want as a side effect, but my end goal here is not sanitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom parser, and empty its internal list of block-level parsers.

```
class Kramdown::Parser::SpanKramdown < Kramdown::Parser::Kramdown
  def initialize(source, options)
    super
    @block_parsers = []
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like  this:

```
text = Kramdown::Document.new(text, :input => 'SpanKramdown').to_html
```

This should do what you want "the right way".